# request for member ... which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, class, member

I get the error

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:43:16: error: request for member 'getF' in 'cor', which is of non-class type 'corMatrixFermion(MatrixV)'
  myfile << cor.getF;
                ^
```

Here is the Header of my class:

```
class MatrixV{
  public:
    MatrixV(std::string file);
    MatrixV(Eigen::MatrixXd matrix);
    MatrixV(double arr[], int arrsize);

    Eigen::MatrixXd getV();
    Eigen::VectorXd getSigma();
    int getr(); 
    Eigen::MatrixXd getO1();
    Eigen::MatrixXd getO2();
    Eigen::MatrixXd getE(); 
    Eigen::MatrixXd getVStrich();

private:
    int size;
    Eigen::MatrixXd V;
    Eigen::VectorXd Sigma;
    int r;
    Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::NoQRPreconditioner> svd;
};
```

And here the main.cpp

```
int main(){
std::srand(time(0));

DataFromFile StartValues("StartValues");

double arr[4];
arr[0]  = StartValues.get(1);
arr[1]  = StartValues.get(2);
arr[2]  = StartValues.get(3);
arr[3]  = StartValues.get(4);

MatrixV V(arr, 4);
corMatrixFermion cor(MatrixV V);

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("corfunction.txt");
myfile << cor.getF();
myfile.close();
}
```

There are other classes involved, but I dont think, that they cause the problem. Do you see, what I'm doing wrong? If you need more information please tell me. It seems to me, that it is not the usual "request for member"-constructor-problem. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: You've posted the class "MatrixV" but not "corMatrixFermion", isn't the problem with the later?

Comment: Besides the parse issue, you don't have a `getF`, but a `getE`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: @StoryTeller `getE` is in another class, `MatrixV`. The definition of `corMatrixFermion` is not shown here.

Comment: @Thomas - Doesn't help the question be any more on-topic. Between a typo, lacking a MCVE and possibly being a dup... It should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks dodgy:

```
corMatrixFermion cor(MatrixV V);
```

This is declaring `cor` to be a function. You probably meant to pass `V` to the `corMatrixFermion` constructor instead:

```
corMatrixFermion cor(V);
```